# create a dict with unique keys and various list values from a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of tuples like this one:

```
[('id1', 'text1', 0, 'info1'),
 ('id2', 'text2', 1, 'info2'),
 ('id3', 'text3', 1, 'info3'),
 ('id1', 'text4', 0, 'info4'),
 ('id4', 'text5', 1, 'info5'),
 ('id3', 'text6', 0, 'info6')]
```

I want to convert it to dict, keeping the ids as keys and all other values as lists of tuples, expanding the ones that aready exist:

```
{'id1': [('text1', 0, 'info1'),
         ('text4', 0, 'info4')],
 'id2': [('text2', 1, 'info2')],
 'id3': [('text3', 1, 'info3'),
         ('text6', 0, 'info6')],
 'id4': [('text5', 1, 'info5')]}
```

Right now I use the pretty simple code:

```
for x in list:
  if x[0] not in list: list[x[0]] = [(x[1], x[2], x[3])]
  else: list[x[0]].append((x[1], x[2], x[3]))
```

I beleive there should be more elegant way to achieve the same result, with generators maybe. Any ideas?

Comment: Please never make a variable called `list`, this shadows a built-in class.

Comment: Yes, ofc, that was just a pure example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A useful method for appending to lists contained in a dictionary for these kind of problems is  [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). You can use it to retrieve an existing list from a dictionary, or add an empty one if it is missing, like so:

```
data = [('id1', 'text1', 0, 'info1'),
        ('id2', 'text2', 1, 'info2'),
        ('id3', 'text3', 1, 'info3'),
        ('id1', 'text4', 0, 'info4'),
        ('id4', 'text5', 1, 'info5'),
        ('id3', 'text6', 0, 'info6')]

x = {}
for tup in data:
    x.setdefault(tup[0], []).append(tup[1:])
```

Result:

```
{'id1': [('text1', 0, 'info1'), ('text4', 0, 'info4')],
 'id2': [('text2', 1, 'info2')],
 'id3': [('text3', 1, 'info3'), ('text6', 0, 'info6')],
 'id4': [('text5', 1, 'info5')]}
```

I actually find the `setdefault` method a bit awkward to use (and some people [agree](https://xion.org.pl/2012/01/28/pythons-setdefault-considered-harmful/)), and always forget how it works exactly. I usually use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(list)
for tup in data:
    x[tup[0]].append(tup[1:])
```

which has similar results.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Bas!

Comment: Great answer! Thanks